# Installing VS Package from code

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vspackage

Is there an API that can be used from .NET code to install/uninstall a Visual Studio Package, for a specific VS version?

The API would take as inputs:

- VSIX file path
- VS version (we'd like to have support for VS2012, VS2013 and further versions)
- a flag to indicate Install or Uninstall

---

Similarly I'd need also an API that tells me if a specific VS Package is installed or not. the The API would take as inputs:

- VSIX file path
- VS version

and would return a boolean: Installed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSIXInstaller.exe can install or uninstall a vsix for for a specific VS version and edition. To check package installation you can use Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell.IsPackageInstalled from VS automation engine.

Comment: Thanks! So starting VSIXInstaller.exe through Process.Start() with the right arguments is the way to go, there are no specific APIs for that?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no specific APIs for that.